# Resize Form in Windows Forms and Localization

Tags: winforms, localization

I have a Windows Form form that I changed the size from the default.  The form is localized so I have resx files associated with it.  When I run the en-us version of the form, the form size shows just fine with the new size.  However, when I run the form using a different language, the size of the form reverts back to the original size.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the form's dimensions in the resx file as well? Depending on how you generated the resx files, sizing information could also be locale-specific.